# Pagination in Search Engine with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, pagination

I am creating an enterprise search engine. I have all my records fro search on a single page. I want to give pagination to my search results with Html and javascript. I have gone through many pagination questions from stackoverflow but I am not understanding any logic of it. Can anyone suggest me some method or code on pagination?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should provide more details. What are your requirments regarding pagination? Should it use some technology like for example jquery, angular, react? Or should be it created using plain JavaScript and DOM? How do you plan to use it?

Comment: Depends on what you wish to do. If you're talking about pagination of data, then I'd recommend you look at JQuery DataTables. Other than that, then you'll probably have to implement that yourself as part of your application.

Comment: hello .. I have created a search engine with solr and i m calling all records from solr core with Solrj.  I want to use Javascript in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways I would normally go with pagination:

- **Server side**: Where you works out the number of records that is matched by the search criteria, and depending on how many records per page send out the relevant data (e.g. 10,000 records in database, 15 per page, then send back 15 records)
- **Client side**: Send back all the records that matched the search criteria, and decide what to show and hide on the client side

Since you did not specify which method you are going with, I'm going to guess it is the server side approach since it is a enterprise search engine.

I am not going to give you any code because I don't even know what JS framework you are going with and there are plenty so simply pick one (AngularJS + Bootstrap + Bootstrap UI). Instead I'll walk you through how I normally go about this.

When the user search for something, query the database and return the total number of records. This means only the total is interested here. Assuming you are using MySQL, either do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo WHERE bar= 'value';` OR using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`.

Then based on how many items you want to display per page, return the relevant number by adding `limit` and `offset` e.g.

`SELECT columns FROM table LIMIT 10 OFFSET 5`.

When return the data I would normally return something like this

```
{
    total: 234,
    data: [
        data1,
        data2,
        ...
    ]
}
```

Using `total` I can workout how many pages to display, and I can then loop through `data` and show it on the page.

If the user clicks on page 5 for example, then if the item per page is 15, then I want to see see record 75 to 90 (assuming starting from record 1).